# Why don't we consider the zero subspace (which is readily $T$-invariant) in the definition of direct sum of linear operators?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

> Why don't we consider the zero subspace (which is readily $T$-invariant) in the definition of direct sum of linear operators?

REF: [Schaum's Outline of Linear Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071794565)

Comment: For the same reason why we do not consider the null vector to be an eigenvector of all operators. Those are only conventions, though, and are only marginally important.

Comment: As far as I realize we don't consider the null vector to be an eigenvector since otherwise all the scalars became the eigenvalues. How is this similar here?

Comment: We can consider the zero subspace, but what a bore and what a triviality! This is, imo, the main reason to put it away.

Comment: Because it would mean that all operators are decomposable, I suspect. I guess we could allow it, and then define "non-trivial" decompositions.  Essentially, we can think of a decomposition as a factoring of the operator, and the null subspace as being like "1" in factorizations.

Comment: To amplify Thomas Andrews's comment: There would be no harm in allowing the zero subspace in the definition of a direct sum (of spaces or of operators), but you don't want it in the definition of "decomposable" because then every operator would be decomposable as the direct sum of itself and the trivial operator obn the zero subspace.  So "decomposable" would become a useless concept.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Usually new concepts are defined in a way so that it covers as much things **as possible** and so triviality comes as immediate subcase. Isn't it sound strange to exclude a case in the definition just because it's trivial?

Comment: Not necessarily @SritiMallick, and it's not the only case: we also usually exclude the case the quotient $\,q=1\,$ is a geometric progression, and the same number is excluded from being the basis for a real logarithm, as it'd be a function defined only in one point. Perhaps "excluded" is not the right term, though: I'd say "put aside" or somethinkg like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, you could.

A decomposition of an operator is much like a factorization of a natural number. We can consider factorizations of numbers with '1' as one of the factor, but then we really are interested in is non-trivial factorizations.

I would prefer your definition, allowing for zero subspaces, but we don't lose much either way. I suspect that is why `(nonzero)` is in parentheses - if they felt it was a hard rule, they wouldn't need to parenthesize that, would they?

Essentially, we are interested in whether an operator is "decomposable." Non-decomposable operators are, in some sense, primes. But all operators are decomposables if we allow for the null space, so we would then need to define non-decomposable as "only has trivial decompositions."

Comment: Indeed. Actually your comment resonate more than your answer with the way I think that considering zero subspace in the definition would left any linear operator decomposable; intuitively then the concept of decomposition of linear operator looses its speciality.

Comment: One more thing; to keep this "speciality" of the definition couldn't we exclude the improper subspace instead of $(0)?$

Comment: Excluding $\{0\}$ excludes the whole space, excluding $V$ doesn't exclude $\{0\}$, except in decompositions into exactly two subspaces. So it would be redundant to exclude $V$ from a decomposition.